# Handling accelerate in different devices

Tags: unity, android, accelerometer

I am adding tilt controls to my game. The sensor values I get are different in different android devices which results in random behavior.

Anyone knows how can I tackle this situation?

I tried normalizing acceleration but it is still the same.

Comment: You could provide a calibration utility.

Comment: Hmm will look into it...will that provide contsant acelration value in all device? In my Xiomi Redmi 1s it's giving me max tilt value of 0.4 whereas in Xiaomi Mi 4 it's goes till 0.9 as max value

Comment: The trick is to get the user to tilt their device to get an idea of the range.  You can then set your values.  I have never done this myself, however, this seems to be the way other developers handle tilt controls.  I am hoping someone chimes in with an answer on this one for you.

Comment: I tried calibration ,but I think its more to do with Low pass filter than to angle at which user is holding device....

Answer (score 0):

I think Jons correct. I don't know what you mean about low pass filter.

One way is to deal in local range values for your game. Like a range of 0-1. 0 is no tilt, 1 is max tilt. Your game always expects 0-1. Then your calibration create values to convert the device values into your to your local range.

So for example, your redmi extent is 0.4.

1.0 / 0.4 == 2.5. You then multiply your redmi device values by 2.5 to get the 0 -> 1 range.

for your Mi 
1.0 / 0.9 == 1.11. You then multiply your Mi device values by 1.11 to get the 0 -> 1 range.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it seems to work on different devices. The motion of putting the phone down gives me a value for the delta x of  -0.5041921 on a samsung galaxy and a -0.5021868 on a Nexus 5.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GyroController : MonoBehaviour {
 //   public Text x, y, z;
    public Dice dice;
    public GameManager gameManger;
    public float lowPassKernelWidhtInSeconds;
    private float acceleromerUpdateInterval;
    private float lowPAssFilterFactor;
    private Vector3 lowPassValue;

    private Vector3 phoneAcc, phoneDeltaAcc;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        acceleromerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
        lowPAssFilterFactor = acceleromerUpdateInterval / lowPassKernelWidhtInSeconds;
        lowPassValue = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
       //x.text ="X: " + Input.gyro.userAcceleration.x;
       //y.text ="Y: " + Input.gyro.userAcceleration.y;
       //z.text ="Z: " + Input.gyro.userAcceleration.z;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        phoneAcc = Input.acceleration;
        phoneDeltaAcc = phoneAcc - LowPassFilter(phoneAcc);

        if(Mathf.Abs(phoneDeltaAcc.x)>=.5)
        {
            dice.RollDice();
            dice.StartSetPlayerRoll(gameManger.activePlayer);
        }

    }
    private Vector3 LowPassFilter( Vector3 newSample)
    {
        lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp(lowPassValue, newSample, lowPAssFilterFactor);
        return lowPassValue;
    }

}
```